# Running two queries for each individual thing

Tags: php

Sorry about the lame title, but I really don't know how to explain it!

Basically, I want to query the game categories from a table, then query games from another table which equal the category of the category queried from the categories table.

Got me so far?

This is the code I have so far...

```
$get_categories_query = mysql_query("
  SELECT * 
    FROM game_categories 
ORDER BY category_name ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories_query)) {
  $category_name      = $row['category_name'];
  $get_category_games = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
      FROM games 
     WHERE category = '$category_name' 
  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_category_games)) {
    $category_game_id    = $row['id'];
    $category_game_title = $row['game_title'];
    $category_game_display .= '<li><img 
      class="category_module_img" 
      src="http://www.game.assets.buddyweb.me/' . 
        $category_game_id . 
        '/_thumb_100x100.png"></li>';
  }
  $category_display .= '<div class = "category_module">
  <h4>'.$category_name.'</h4>
  '.$category_game_display.'
  <div class="play_more_btn">More</div>
  </div>';
}
```

But what I get from that is every game appearing from the query from the first category in the list.

Comment: Everytime in the inner while() you write over the $category_game_* stuff. Don't you want to echo / keep all titles and displays?

Comment: I need the game titles are stuff!

Comment: make $category_game_* arrays and append to them in the inner while loop.

Comment: um excuse me? And what does that mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the $row variable.

Try this:

```
$get_categories_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game_categories ORDER BY category_name ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_categories_query))
{
    $category_name = $row['category_name'];
    $get_category_games = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE category = '$category_name' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
    $category_game_display = false; // new!!

    while($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($get_category_games))
    {
        $category_game_id = $row_cat['id'];
        $category_game_title = $row_cat['game_title'];
        $category_game_display .= '<li><img class = "category_module_img" src = "http://www.game.assets.buddyweb.me/'.$category_game_id.'/_thumb_100x100.png"></li>';
    }

    $category_display .= '<div class = "category_module"><h4>'.$category_name.'</h4>'.$category_game_display.'<div class = "play_more_btn">More</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: I don't think you guys know what I mean, http://awesomescreenshot.com/0eal2h2de it is showing all of the games from the PUZZLES category on every one, when I want the SPORTS category to show only the games from the SPORTS category. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Sorry but it's very hard without any database schema. Is it possible to post it?

Comment: Ok! I insert a new line in the code, I think that was the problem!?

Comment: I'm still having the issue! :(